Mouseover action succeeds inconsistently
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10));
          
element = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("User Maintenance")));
        
action.moveToElement(element).perform();
           
Thread.sleep(1000);
    
element = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("CCS 2021: Form I & Form II submission")));
    element.click();

If the element gets clicked it works sometimes.

you may want to try doing this with one actionschain.... so hover, pause, movebyoffset, click..... build/perform.  (I'm thinking the element .click() method may reset cursor position, loose focus)
